# Three.js Spotlight ShadowCameraHelper Position Incorrect

Tags: three.js

Three.js r76

I was building a JSFiddle example for a slightly different problem but now can't get the shadow `CameraHelper` in the correct place to continue setting up my demo.

The spotlight helper appears to be working correctly but the shadow camera helper just seems to be parked at `(0, 0, 0)` and looking down the z axis.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please? Thank you.

[JS Fiddle of Shadow Camera Helper seemingly in the wrong place](https://jsfiddle.net/n57kjtcs/15/)

Code:

```
spt.position.set(0, 1000, 1000);

  spt.castShadow = true;
  spt.angle = 0.3;
  spt.exponent = 2.0;
  spt.penumbra = 0.05;
  spt.decay = 1;
  spt.distance = 3000;
  spt.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
  spt.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
  spt.shadow.camera.near = 10;
  spt.shadow.camera.far = 6000;
  spt.shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(spt.shadow.camera);
  lightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spt);

  scene.add(spt.shadowCameraHelper);
  scene.add(lightHelper);
  scene.add(spt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable Shadows in the renderer to get the `CameraHelper` to work:

`renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;`

https://jsfiddle.net/n57kjtcs/17/